# tracking member change history on oracle

Tags: oracle, recursion

I was trying to write query to track member change history but I got a problem now.
This is the table I use below,

```
CURRENT_NO, NEW_MEMBER_NO, OLD_MEMBER_NO, SEQ_NO
----------  -------------  -------------  ------ 
 M002       M001           M000           1  
 M002       M002           M001           1  
            M100           M004           1  
            M100           M005           1  
            M101           M100           1  
            M201           M200           1 
            M200           M201           2
```

What I want to do is to track the member_no change history and update CURRENT_NO column as currnet member no.

this is the result I want below

```
CURRENT_NO, NEW_MEMBER_NO, OLD_MEMBER_NO, SEQ_NO
----------  -------------  -------------  ------
 M002       M001           M000           1
 M002       M002           M001           1

 M101       M100           M004           1
 M101       M100           M005           1
 M101       M101           M100           1

 M200       M201           M200           1
 M200       M200           M201           2
```

with OLD_MEMBER_NO at the first row, I search NEW_MEMBER_NO and if I find it then update CURRENT_NO at 1st row as NEW_MEMBER_NO at 2nd row.

CURRENT_NO column show a current member no each row.

1)member M000 changed to M001, from M001 to M002 so now CURRENT_NO column is M002 on both row
2) it is sometimes complecated. M004 and M005 -> M100 -> M101
   this change is possible. CURRENT_NO is all M101 for this case.
3) M200 -> M201, then it change again from M201 to M200. bigger SEQ_NO is new one. so CURRENT_NO is M200 for this case.


And I tried to use query like belo,,....

```
UPDATE 
       (SELECT A.MBR_# AS MBR_#, 
              b.NEW_MBR_# AS B_NEW_MBR_#, 
              B.OLD_MBR_# AS B_OLD_MBR_#, 
              A.NEW_MBR_# AS A_NEW_MBR_#, 
              A.OLD_MBR_# AS A_OLD_MBR_#  
         FROM BI_MEMBER_HISTORY A, 
              BI_MEMBER_HISTORY B  
        WHERE B.OLD_MBR_# = A.NEW_MBR_#
       ) 
SET MBR_# = B_NEW_MBR_#;
```

The problem is 
1) there are sometime more than 2 changed.
2) and example no.3 above.. this makes me complicated to write query.. I know my query has some problem. 

I tried to use procedure with cursor or recursive query but I have no idea how to deal with it.
Could anyone give me a clue?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your requirements, you can find the current number for each row with the a query like this:

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS (
  2  SELECT 'M001' new_no, 'M000' old_no, 1 seq FROM dual
  3  UNION ALL SELECT 'M002', 'M001', 1 FROM dual
  4  UNION ALL SELECT 'M100', 'M004', 1 FROM dual
  5  UNION ALL SELECT 'M100', 'M005', 1 FROM dual
  6  UNION ALL SELECT 'M101', 'M100', 1 FROM dual
  7  UNION ALL SELECT 'M201', 'M200', 1 FROM dual
  8  UNION ALL SELECT 'M200', 'M201', 2 FROM dual
  9  )
 10  SELECT root old_no,
 11         MAX(new_no)
 12            KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY seq DESC, lvl DESC) current_no
 13    FROM (SELECT connect_by_root(old_no) root,
 14                 level lvl, new_no, old_no, seq
 15            FROM DATA
 16          CONNECT BY NOCYCLE PRIOR new_no = old_no)
 17   GROUP BY root;

OLD_NO CURRENT_NO
------ ----------
M000   M002
M001   M002
M004   M101
M005   M101
M100   M101
M200   M200
M201   M200
```

The inner query builds the list of all children for each `old_no` and keep track of the root with [`CONNECT_BY_ROOT`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/operators004.htm#i1035022).

The outer query selects among all descendants the last child of the lineage (`level desc`) from the last lineage sequence (`seq desc`) for each root.

You can merge the result of this query into your table:

```
MERGE INTO (your_table) t
     USING (above_query) q
        ON (t.old_no = q.old_no)
    WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET t.current_no = q.current_no;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. it seems like recursive query, isn't it? as far as I know it is supported on oracle 11g. I am using 10g. and.. I have more than 10,000 rows in table. I guess I need to analyze your query. thank you!

Comment: This query should work fine on 10g. `CONNECT_BY_ROOT` and `NO CYCLE` are 10g features I think. Standard hierarchical queries have been available for a **very very very** long time ([Oracle 2](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Oracle_2)!!! A few months before I was born :).